# How to implement login and register?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I have two forms: (login form, register form) and they submitted to my component.

Login form:
I want to check login and pass and set status to "logged" in joomla.

Register form:
I want register new user in joomla.

How to do it?

```
$inplogin = JRequest::getVar('inplogin');
$inppass = JRequest::getVar('inppass');

???? JFactory::login($inplogin, $inppass); ????

???? JFactory::registeruser($inplogin, $inppass); ????
```

???

Comment: matanya, you don't use $_Session with Joomla. Joomla has its own session store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Login

```
$result = JFactory::getApplication()->login(array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));
```

For Registration

```
require_once  JPATH_ROOT.DS.'components'.DS.'com_users'.DS.'models'.DS.'registration.php';
$model = new UsersModelRegistration();
jimport('joomla.mail.helper');

// Attempt to save the data.
jimport('joomla.user.helper');
$username = ; //your user name here
$password = ; //your password here
$data = array(  'username'=>$email,'name'=>$email,'email1'=>$email,'password1'=>$password, 'password2'=>$password, 'block'=>1 );
$return = $model->register($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is related specifically to joomla.

you need to use the same $_SESSION variable in both cases. after you declare the variable, you can check on the beginning of your index page if this var exists (and if so, whether the credentials are correct or not). something like:

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']) {
    header("location:login.php");
    exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JUser::bind($userData) and JUser::save($userData) for registering the user.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Gaurav's answer:

If you're using just the Joomla framework and you don't have a site loaded, you will still need to initialize the site.

That said, these two lines should do the trick:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
```